# TextView not showing in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have some pop ups in my project which work perfectly, but this one seems to not work, he only shows the buttons, the textviews don't appear (Sorry for bad eng) I tried to use other layouts, but don't looks good at all... what I wanna do is simple use 3 textviews in the middle of screen, if you guys could help me with that i would be glad

popadd.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/dialog_round">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btCancelar"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cancel"
    android:tint="#ffffff"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="90dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btEnviar"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/certo"
    android:tint="#ffffff"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Adicionar amigo"
    android:textSize="70px"
    android:textColor="#454545"
    android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enviar solicitação de amizade para"
    android:textSize="40px"
    android:textColor="#454545"
    android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvNome"
    android:text="Carregando..."
    android:textSize="40px"
    android:textColor="#454545"
    android:layout_marginTop="270dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try to set `android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"` .

Comment: If i set that i'll have a little ball instead of a popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/dialog_round">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btCancelar"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="90dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cancel"
    android:tint="#ffffff"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btEnviar"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/certo"
    android:tint="#ffffff"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Adicionar amigo"
        android:textColor="#454545"
        android:textSize="70px"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Enviar solicitação de amizade para"
        android:textColor="#454545"
        android:textSize="40px"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Carregando..."
        android:textColor="#454545"
        android:textSize="40px"/>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That's it, thank you! I just add android:paddingBottom="70dp" to LinearLayout and works fine.